# Electron - how to handle in page popups

Tags: javascript, electron

Inside electron I'm loading an old site.

The code is simple:
`browserWindow.loadURL('https://myOldSite.com');`

This old site opens a popup (e.g. `<a target="_blank"...>` or even js `window.open`) when a user clicks a button.

When the popup opens, I see something flashing on screen, but it doesn't stay open.  I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to prevent this flash?
2. Is there a way to control this popup and show it to the user? Or get its URL in some way?

Comment: As far as i know you must change the code of the old site. But i would be happy if someone has an idea.

Comment: You should load the URL into an iframe instead of opening a new browser window

Comment: @Our_Benefactors what would that achieve?  Could you share a code sample please?

Comment: @yccteam it avoids opening a new window by loading the content in a separate HTML element, but still part of the same page. There are lots of examples on stackoverflow and elsewhere. Here's some barebones, but easy to understand examples: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it should work as expected. Both `window.open` and `<a target="_blank" ... >` opens a new electron BrowserWindow.

However, you can manipulate the window opening process in *main process* by [`'new-window'` event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-new-window):

```
myBrowserWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => win.show())
  win.loadURL(url)
  event.newGuest = win
})
```

*This example gracefully shows the new window but you can achieve a lot more with available callback arguments*

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the `preload` option when creating your `BrowserWindow`.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions):

> `preload` String (optional) - Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page. This script will always have access to node APIs no matter whether node integration is turned on or off. The value should be the absolute file path to the script. When node integration is turned off, the preload script can reintroduce Node global symbols back to the global scope. See example [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/process.md#event-loaded).

Your preload script could search the page for the links you mentioned and change their behavior. (I.e., send an event to your main process instead to do whatever action you like; open a window, etc.)